SQL generate columns using rows data from other table
I am trying to create a data set which shows what all tests are performed for a patient from a sql table as shown below. Add values from rows to new table columns.
    Input data:
    
    | patient_id | test_id        | test_name | 
    | ---------- | -------------- | --------- |
    | 010        | A11            | blood     |
    | ---------- | -------------- |-----------|
    | 010        | A12            | stool     |
    | ---------- | -------------- |-----------|
    | 010        | A13            | xray      |
    | ---------- | -------------- |-----------|
    | 011        | A13            | xray      |
    | ---------- | -------------- |-----------|
    | 012        | A12            | stool     |
    | ---------- | -------------- |-----------|
    
    Expected result:
    
    When test_id = A11 Then add value to column clinic_test
    When test_id = A12 Then add value to column lab_test
    When test_id = A12 Then add value to column radio_test
    
    expected sample data:
    
    | patient_id | clinic_test | lab_test | radio_test |
    | ---------- |------------ | -------- | ---------- |
    | 010        | blood       | stool    | xray       |
    | ---------- |------------ | -------- | ---------- |
    | 011        | null        | null     | xray       |
    | ---------- |------------ | -------- | ---------- |
    | 012        | null        | stool    | null       |
    | ---------- |------------ | -------- | ---------- |
    
  

Tried case statement but it is giving me 5 rows instead of 3 as expected above
  (
    CASE
      WHEN test_id = A11 THEN test_name
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) clinic_test ,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN test_id  = A12 THEN test_name
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) lab_test,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN test_id = A13 THEN test_name
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) radio_test
  


You can use PIVOT:
SELECT *
FROM   data
       PIVOT(
         LISTAGG(test_name, ',')
         FOR test_id IN (
           'A11' AS clinic_test,
           'A12' AS lab_test,
           'A13' AS radio_test
         )
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE data (patient_id, test_id, test_name) AS
SELECT '010', 'A11', 'blood' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010', 'A12', 'stool' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010', 'A13', 'xray'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '011', 'A13', 'xray'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '012', 'A12', 'stool' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PATIENT_ID
CLINIC_TEST
LAB_TEST
RADIO_TEST




010
blood
stool
xray


011
null
null
xray


012
null
stool
null



fiddle

What you need is a conditional aggregation in order to return single row per each different patient_id such as
SELECT patient_id, 
       MAX(
           CASE
               WHEN test_id = 'A11' THEN test_name
            END
       ) AS clinic_test,
       MAX(
           CASE
               WHEN test_id = 'A12' THEN test_name
            END
       ) AS lab_test ,
       MAX(
           CASE
               WHEN test_id = 'A13' THEN test_name
            END
       ) AS radio_test  
 FROM t
GROUP BY patient_id

Here is the online Demo
